# How to show nested attribute in ActiveAdmin Show Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have some nested model -

**exceed_assessment** - has_many - **assessment_infos**,

**assessment_info** - has_many - **questions**

To show assessment_info on ActiveAdmin of Exceed::Assessment, I use

```
show do
    attributes_table do

      row :guideline

      table_for exceed_assessment.assessment_infos do
        column "information" do |info|
          info.information
        end
      end
    end
  active_admin_comments
  end
```

Its work fine and show all informations, So I use same approach for Question that are belongs_to Assessment_info.

```
table_for exceed_assessment.assessment_infos do
        column "information" do |info|
          info.information
          table_for info.questions do
            column "question" do |que|
              que.question
            end
          end
        end
      end
```

This time it show All Questions, but Information are not showing.
I don't know why it not showing Information that show in past.

How can I show multi level nested attributes on ActiveAdmin Show page?

Comment: Here is a simple solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11818230/1770571
It works for me